# Can I deploy Linux/Ubuntu from a wim file?

Tags: 13.04

I would like to put Linux on to a install.wim file. Is it possible to deploy in this way?

Comment: What is a "wim file" exactly? Ask about the software you want to deploy with, not one specific file format it can use.

Comment: @dobey (cant comment need 50 rep) The Windows Imaging Format (WIM) is a file-based disk image format. It was developed by Microsoft to help deploy Windows Vista and subsequent versions of Windows operating system family, as well as Windows Fundamentals for Legacy PCs.

Answer (score 1):

Hypothetically yes, but there could be a few problems. I would not recommend using an archive format designed for Windows operating systems to deploy a Linux system, though I understand why it might be tempting. Consider using .tar instead of .wim.

Problem #1 = Grub2 Boot Manager won't be installed so you'll have no way to boot the deployed system, though "boot-repair" run from a livecd might be able to fix this.

To install boot-repair use:

```
sudo apt-get install boot-repair
```

To run boot-repair use:

```
boot-repair
```

Problem #2 = There aren't many programs available for creating wims so you'll probably have to use imagex or dism both of which are only available for Windows operating systems. I suppose you might be able to use p7zip (the linux version of 7-zip if it supports wim?), but it won't use compression. If you use dism or imagex Windows can't read ext2/ext3/ext4 systems so you can't make an image if you can't access the partition. You may be able to run dism or imagex in Wine or you can install a special driver on Windows like the one that Paragon makes, or there is another one I can't recall the name of to add filesystem support to Windows. It's also worth noting that imagex doesn't support extended attributes, which I believe Ubuntu uses.

Problem #3 = Will the .wim be able to retain linux file permissions. If it doesn't your deployed system will have all files belonging to whatever user extracted the .wim which would leave your system very unprotected since Linux systems rely almost entirely on file permissions to protect themselves from viruses and hackers. It may also affect the systems ability to run? Will it even be able to read certain types of linux files that aren't supported in Windows?

Problem #4 = When you deploy to a new hard drive Grub2 bootloader will remember the UUID of the drive you installed to. You won't be able to boot on any other systems unless you use a linux live cd to change the UUID of the partition you are deploying to to match the original drive's UUID. You can do this with tune2fs.

To find the UUID of your source partition use:

```
sudo blkid
```

To change the UUID of the partition being deployed to use:

```
sudo tune2fs /dev/sda1 -U theuuidgoeshere
```